# Nginx ssl_verify_client and proxy_pass

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have 2 Nginx servers **server1** and **server2**. 
**server1** requires client ssl verification.
**server2** proxies all request to server1

The problem is while i am trying to access my service directly from server1 the browser asks my client certificate and it works fine

But from servier2 it always gives error "400 Bad Request. No required SSL certificate was sent"

server1 nginx config is

```
server {
listen       443;
server_name  server1 ;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/client_keys/keys.crt;
ssl_verify_client on;
ssl_verify_depth 1;
ssl_session_timeout 5m;
ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1;
ssl_ciphers ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv3:+EXP;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

location / {
    proxy_pass https://some-service;
}
}
```

server2 nginx config is

```
server {
listen       443  default_server;
server_name  server2;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/client_keys/keys.crt;
location / {
    proxy_pass https://server1;
}
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment, that is not supported in nginx. But there is senginx[1], it's proxy module is extended to support client certificate handshake with origin server.

[1] http://www.senginx.org/en/index.php/Proxy_HTTPS_Client_Certificate